# FlowEnt Tweening Library Gradient

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've recently started using the FlowEnt Tweening library and I was wondering how i could go about using a gradient to control the colour of lights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to use the Gradient on a Light all you have to do is create a new tween, apply all the options and then use the implemented extension method that creates the motion

```
Gradient gradient;
Light light;
new Tween().SetTime(2f).For(light).ColorTo(gradient).Start();
```

Don't forget to call start after you apply all options and motions!

Comment: Can you also use the gradient to control other tweens?

Comment: Yes! You can you the same gradient for any tweens you like.